# (FIXED, thankyou) When Loop Cutting and altering the form of model, there is a another model above it. How to fix please?

Tags: modeling, objects

Here are the basics:

- **Mode:** Edit Mode, Modeling
- **Modifier:** Mirroring, Axis X, Clipping, Merge 0.001 m
- **Methods:** Loop Cut via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, Loop Cut via the tool, Knife shortcut/tool
- **When:** resizing <kbd>S</kbd>, or grabbing <kbd>G</kbd>, and trying to size or grab it inward, there is another layer atop the same model 'faces'. When in x-ray mode, it's as though there are two "skin layers" even though the model is singular. The knife tool also will not cut properly despite it working earlier in the project. The dual skin also was not occurring earlier either. Is there a function that causes this that was accidentally pressed?

***the weird dual skin thing is happening only after cutting.**

Also, I opened a new blend file and did the same things with the starting cube and there was no weird thing. I copied and pasted the model to the new blend file, and put it in edit mode, and the issue is still there. It must be something with the model.  **thank you, this is the first time. I hope someone knows the fix. Again, thank you*

[image: Workspace, before and after Loop Cutting with resizing/grabbing causing duplicate original layers, resizing/grabbing in a not cut points results in no weirdness]
Workspace, before and after Loop Cutting with resizing/grabbing causing duplicate original layers, resizing/grabbing in a not cut points results in no weirdness.

Comment: Have you checked if there are overlapping faces? In *Edit* mode, press key '3' for *Face Selection* mode, select a face, and hide it with key 'H'. If there is still a face then you have some overlapping faces. ('Alt+H' to reveal the hidden faces)

Comment: Please share your Blend file so that we can have a look: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions.

Comment: My guess is duplicated geometry with proportional editing enabled but as @johneason mentioned would need a blend file to pin it down

Comment: Ah, that was the issue - there were two layers haha, thank you.